# Git repository is corrupted after migrating from MacOS to Ubuntu, via Google Drive

Tags: git

I have a small project that was being developed on a single MacOS computer. Said computer was unfortunately stolen, and I recovered it from a cloud backup on Google Drive.
I understand this is not best practice but it was the only option at the time given organisational restrictions.

Opening the backup repository on an Ubuntu computer has these problems:

1. A good chunk of the latest commits are missing. (The latest checked out files are still in the folder, so the loss of work is small).
2. Most git commands (`git log`, `git status`, etc.) will work but display this error: `error: unable to open object pack directory: .git/objects/pack: Not a directory`.

.git/objects/pack seems in fact to be an empty file.

What can be the cause of this and can it be repaired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most cloud backup services have some system service that runs and uploads data as it changes or periodically. However, these systems are designed to upload individual files, not multiple files that represent atomic snapshots, like Git repositories or databases, and they don't provide POSIX filesystem guarantees. Consequently, using cloud backup services to store repositories is very likely to corrupt your repository.

If you have a repository on a Git hosting service, like GitHub, try using that instead. If you don't, you can try removing the `.git/objects/pack` file and running `git init`. That will replace it with an appropriate directory, and then you can try further recovery, including running `git fsck`. Dangling objects are generally okay, but other items can indicate problems.

If, in the future, you need to back up a repository to a cloud backup service, create a tarball of the entire repository and upload that instead. That will guarantee that you have a consistent snapshot that can be recovered in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you use git, I guess your work is saved on a remote server (Github or personal server). If you have managed your code well, you should be able to retrieve your work at the time of your last commit from your Ubuntu computer via the following command:

```
git clone https://*URL of the project on the git server*
```

Your .git directory will be automatically generated